# iOS Swift: How to calculate the sum of each value in a key-pair dictionary and store it in a separate dictionary?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

Currently I have a dictionary array that is defined like so:

```
var dateDouble_ARRAY = [Date : [Double] ]()

dateDouble_ARRAY = [2017-08-06 07:00:00 +0000: [11.880000000000001, 3.0], 
    2013-08-08 07:00:00 +0000: [5.0], 
    2016-08-01 07:00:00 +0000: [6.0], 
    2017-08-09 07:00:00 +0000: [6.0], 
    2013-08-02 07:00:00 +0000: [5.0], 
    2012-08-03 07:00:00 +0000: [6.5499999999999998], 
    2015-08-10 07:00:00 +0000: [2.0] ]
```

What I would like to do is get the year of all the dates and store it in a `[String: Double]` key-value dictionary where the value paired up with the year key is the **sum** of all the values for that **specific** year.

For example, in the above code, the following would be the desired output:

```
var yearDouble_ARRAY = [ "2012": 6.5499999999999998, 
                         "2013": 10.0, 
                         "2015": 2.0, 
                         "2016": 6.0, 
                         "2017: 20.880000000000001]
```

**NOTE:** For "2017", `20.880000000000001` is obtained from `[ (11.880000000000001 + 3.0) + 6.0]`.

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Thanks!

**What I have tried so far**

```
var stringDates = [String: Int]()

for (index, date) in dateDouble_ARRAY.enumerated()
{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"

    let yearOnly = formatter.string(from: date.key)

    stringDates[yearOnly] = index
}

let yearOnly_ARRAY = stringDates.keys.sorted()
```

However, I was only able to store the non-repeated years, I'm not sure how to sum the values associated with the year.

Comment: What have you tried? SO it is not a code it for me website

Comment: I did not vote you down. It is not my down vote but totally understandable. BTW you have way more reputation than the OP you linked 4+ years against 1 week). you should know already the website rules

Comment: dateDouble_ARRAY is a dictionary not an array. yearDouble_ARRAY it is also a dictionary. You should choose better names for your variables. they are totally misleading

Comment: Another misleading name is `date` in your for loop. date in your loop it is a key value tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was only missing the sum of the current Doubles:

```
let datesDoubles = [
    Date(): [11.880000000000001, 3.0],
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600 * 24 * 60 * -1 ): [6.0],
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600 * 24 * 365 * -1): [5.0],
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600 * 24 * 365 * -1 * 2): [6.0],
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600 * 24 * 365 * -1 * 4): [5.0],
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600 * 24 * 365 * -1 * 5): [6.5499999999999998],
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600 * 24 * 365 * -1 * 6): [2.0]
]

var stringDates = [String : Double]()
let formatter: DateFormatter = {
    $0.dateFormat = "yyyy"
    return $0
}(DateFormatter())

for dateDouble in datesDoubles {
    let yearOnly = formatter.string(from: dateDouble.key)

    if let valueForDate = stringDates[yearOnly] {
        stringDates[yearOnly] = valueForDate + dateDouble.value.reduce(0,+)
    } else {
        stringDates[yearOnly] = dateDouble.value.reduce(0,+)
    }
}

print(stringDates)
```